# How to change from gameplay camera to menu camera when colliding with a game object?

Tags: unity, c#, camera

I want to know how to change which camera is outputting to the screen when colliding with another game object in Unity.

I'm making platformer, and at the end of the level I want to switch from the player camera to the game menu camera (since they're in the same scene).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more flexible way to do it with a reusable, general purpose trigger script:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider2D))]
public class Trigger2DEvents : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private UnityEvent onTriggerEnter;
    [SerializeField] private UnityEvent onTriggerExit;

    private void Awake() {
        var collider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(collider);
        Assert.IsTrue(collider.isTrigger);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) {
        onTriggerEnter.Invoke();
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision) {
        onTriggerExit.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Attach that script to a GameObject with a 2D collider with "is trigger" selected. Then add two event listeners to the "On Trigger Enter" event - one that disables the game camera, and one that enables the menu camera.

[image: Unity inspector]

You can reuse this component to set up other game events that are activated by triggers, without having to write code each time.

Comment: thx bro! this'll help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Make an empty game object and give it a 2D collider with "Is Trigger" checked, so it can detect when an object enters its area without making it bounce off.

Add a script like this to that object:

```cs
public class CameraTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera cameraToActivate;

    // Delete the two "2D" instances if your platformer is 3D.
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        // You can add code here to check what "other" object
        // entered our trigger, and abort if it's not the right one.
        // But a better solution is to put this trigger volume on
        // a physics layer that collides *only* with the right object(s).

        // Turn off the currently active main camera
        // (first enabled camera in scene with the "MainCamera" tag)
        Camera.main.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        // Turn on the designated camera set in the inspector.
        cameraToActivate.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Populate the `cameraToActivate` variable to point to the menu camera you want to turn on.

Make sure the camera you want to turn off has the "MainCamera" tag.

To switch back, do the opposite: use `SetActive()` to turn the menu camera off, and the gameplay/player camera back on.

To make sure you don't have two cameras active at once, you can start the game with one of them inactive (untick the checkbox at the top of the inspector when selecting the camera object in the scene), or add a method to auto-disable one on start-up:

```cs
void Start() { cameraToActivate.gameObject.SetActive(false); }
```

Basics like this are covered in almost every beginner Unity tutorial, so I recommend working your way through a few more introductory guides to ensure you have the fundamentals down.

Comment: hey, i know i sound really stupid because i should probably know this but i tried out the script and it works but it's not automatically switching to the active camera, how do i do that as well?

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem. Post a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example if you want help troubleshooting.

Comment: ok i'll post it soon